# Data filtering using external data in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

[Data sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KUXn.png)
2 data sources 
1. Custom SQL Query
2. clipboard data

I have 2 tables both with serial numbers in it. Data source Custom SQL Query is the superset.
I want to exclude serial numbers given in clipboard while using custom SQL Query data source.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this  `Boolean` calculation

```
Custom_SQL.serial_numbers=Clipboard.Serial_numbers
```

exclude `True` you will have all the `Serial numbers` from the  `Custom_SQL.serial_numbers` but not from `Clipboard.Serial_numbers`

Comment: Hi Vijay, One more help. Filter do not work on all the sheets. Any idea why not working?